# No me cargan imágenes con Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Estoy creando una pequeña app con Next.js, y no me están leyendo los archivos binarios (según el error), o sea me da error al usar `<img />` o el nuevo componente de Next `Image from 'next/image'`

Así está el código:

```
import React from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image'

import { DecorationPoint, HeaderTag } from './style'

import LogoRestaurant from '../../public/images/logo-restaurant.png'

export const Header = () => {

   return(
      <HeaderTag>
         <DecorationPoint />
         <div>
            <h1>
               <Image src='/images/logo-restaurant.png' alt='Logo'/>
            </h1>
         </div>
      </HeaderTag>
   )
}
```

Y me da este error:

```
error - ./public/images/logo-restaurant.png 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

Hasta donde tengo entendido no se necesita configurar eso en Next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo creo el error te lo da por haber agregado:

```
import LogoRestaurant from '../../public/images/logo-restaurant.png'
```

Nunca he trabajado con next.js, pero [revisando la documentación](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving), no deberías importar las imágenes, como lo estás tratando de hacer en esa línea, sino tener las imágenes en tu carpeta `public` y cargarlas tal cual ya lo estás haciendo:

```
import Image from 'next/image'
//...luego más abajo
<Image src='/images/logo-restaurant.png' alt='Logo'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta exportando Image pero no lo estas utilizando

Manda a llamar así

```
<Image src='/images/logo-restaurant.png 
alt='logo' >
</Image>
```